# Static Method returning None result?

Tags: python, oop

Im trying to create a class that has a static method in it which converts currency. This is the code I have used. However, when I try to use it such as the attempt in the code. I get a value of None returned and I am not sure why? I need to call this in my main program. Any advice, thanks?

```
class CurrencyConversion:

@staticmethod
def currency_converter(base_currency='Eur', base_amount=0.0, quote_cur=''):
    if base_currency == 'Eur' and quote_cur == 'USD':
        cal_quoted_amount = base_amount * 1.07
        return cal_quoted_amount
    elif base_currency == 'USD' and quote_cur == 'Eur':
        cal_quoted_amount = base_amount * 0.93
        return cal_quoted_amount
    elif base_currency == 'Eur' and quote_cur == 'GBP':
        cal_quoted_amount = base_amount * 0.83
        return cal_quoted_amount
    elif base_currency == 'GBP' and quote_cur == 'Eur':
        cal_quoted_amount = base_amount * 1.20
        return cal_quoted_amount
    elif base_currency == 'USD' and quote_cur == 'GBP':
        cal_quoted_amount = base_amount * 0.78
        return cal_quoted_amount
    elif base_currency == 'GBP' and quote_cur == 'USD':
        cal_quoted_amount = base_amount * 1.28
        return cal_quoted_amount

 print(CurrencyConversion.currency_converter('USD', 5.55, 'EUR'))
```

Comment: The values passed in don't meet any of your checks in the `if` and `elif` clauses. `Eur` is different from `EUR`. You probably want to return some default value if all checks fail in any case, or perhaps throw an error.

Comment: You should probably have a `raise ValueError` or something at the end